# Scrapy doesn't crawl

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

```py
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import scrapy

    class ProvasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'provas'
        allowed_domains = ['folhadirigida.com.br']
        start_urls = ['https://folhadirigida.com.br/']

        def parse(self, response): #criando pagina
            page = response.url.split ("/")[-3]
            filename = '%s.html' % page
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.body)
```

When I run this program, to crawl [this page](https://folhadirigida.com.br/), I get: [image: this image]. 
For example, if i run the same program on [this page](https://g1.globo.com/), I get an exact copy of this page. Why does it not work with the first page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of missing `<base href="https://folhadirigida.com.br/">` in your HTML page, it does not look fine to you.

```py
import scrapy

class ProvasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'provas'
    allowed_domains = ['folhadirigida.com.br']
    start_urls = ['https://folhadirigida.com.br/']

    def parse(self, response): #criando pagina
        page = response.url.split ("/")[-2]
        filename = '%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            ref_body = response.body[:42] + b'<base href="https://folhadirigida.com.br/">'\
                       + response.body[42:]
            f.write(ref_body)
```

Adding it to your HTML body like this code will make page looks fine.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain to me how you found this result?

Comment: I compared the HTML file we saved with `view(response)` HTML code in shell which seemed to be fine.